# Importing WordPress options using php

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am working on a project and which is using whitelabel options plugin, I want to import those options using radium one click import library. As radium does not support white label plugin, I want to do same thing with my options. Currently, my options are imported using this script.

```
jQuery('#tnit_buttons1_0').click(function(e){
    //jQuery('.radium-import-start').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         var r = confirm("Press a button!");
         if (r == true){
        var dataString = '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';

            //$('#import_field').val();

            jQuery.post(
                ajaxurl, 
                {
                    'action': js_options_data[10] + '_import_options',
                    'data':   dataString
                }, 
                function(response){
                    $(window).off("beforeunload");
                    location.reload();
                }
            );
         }
         else {
             return;
         }
    });
```

I just want to import my data once that radium one click button is clicked. I am able to find that function but unable to put my above code by converting in php so that it can work properly for me. Simply, I want this options to import using php not jquery.

**Note:** var dataString contains string which is used to import my options.

Comment: Then you should check, what is the action in the `js_options_data[10] + '_import_options'`, then check what happens in the ajax file on that action.

Comment: where to find that action ? that's the all culprit ...

Comment: in your jquery use `console.log('The option is: ' + js_options_data[10] + '_import_options');`